# how create a credential with opensaml-j?

Tags: java, opensaml

Hi i hope you are all okey
i am using opensaml-j v3 and i'm trying so hard to create a credential with this latter but i don't know how to create it .

here is my source code

```
   `private static Credential getCredential() throws IOException, 
          NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, CertificateException{
       InputStream is=new FileInputStream("C:\\openssl keys\\key.pk8");
       CertificateFactory cf=CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
       X509Certificate cer=(X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
       BasicX509Credential basicCredential=new BasicX509Credential(cer);
       basicCredential.setUsageType(UsageType.SIGNING);
       return basicCredential;
}`
```

here's the stack trace

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
 at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
 at memory.CreateSamlAssertion.getCredential(CreateSamlAssertion.java:108)
 at memory.CreateSamlAssertion.createAssertion(CreateSamlAssertion.java:61)
 at memory.SamlTest.main(SamlTest.java:42)
```

the error is in this line:

`X509Certificate cer=(X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);`

so I just have a simple question :

can someone show me a source code how to create a credential??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your file you should create a .csr file
here's a link: [create a .csr file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)
after the creation follow this snippet of code

```
private static String password="jkzhsmzku";//the password you set in the storepass
private static String alias="business"//this is the alias;

private static Credential getCredential(){
    char[] pass=password.toCharArray();
    KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("pathToFile/fileName.csr");
    ks.load(fis, pass);
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry=null;
    pkEntry=(PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias,new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray()));
    PrivateKey pk=pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
    X509Certificate certificate=(X509Certificate) pkEntry.getCertificate();
    BasicX509Credential basicCredential=new BasicX509Credential(certificate);
    basicCredential.setPrivateKey(pk);
    return basicCredential;
}
```